# How to update a cookie properly?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am creating and setting a cookie via the code snippet I created below.

When I try to grab the `document.cookie` to verify that my cookie was created properly, I see a *discrepancy*.

**Allow me to elaborate:**

I am using a 50/50 random number generator, generated by the `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)` and stored within `cookieValue`. Therefore, I ensure I always have a 0 or a 1 as my cookie value. This, as well as the rest of the parameters will be part of `cookieStr`, which will be passed onto the `document.cookie` in order to create a cookie.

However, in order to verify that this properly occurred, I need to make sure that the current cookie `SomeCookieName` has the same value as the output of my `console.log(cookieStr)`. Meaning I am properly updating the cookie dynamically.

One quick look at the code below (in the console) and I can tell something is amiss. It always has `SomeCookieName` of 0, where as the random number generator will output 0 and 1 respectively.

**TL;DR**:

I believe I am not properly updating the value of the `SomeCookieName` parameter properly, which should be either `0` or `1` based on the `cookieValue` random function; but I don't know why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
var hoursToAdd = 3,
    daysToAdd = 10,
    cookieValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2), // Random value 0 or 1
    cookieName = "SomeCookieName",
    cookiePath = "/",
    cookieDomain = "*.somedomainname.com";

setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, 0, hoursToAdd, cookiePath, cookieDomain);

console.log(document.cookie);

function setCookie(c_name, c_value, c_exdays, c_exhours, c_path, c_domain) {
  var exdate = new Date(),
      cookieStr = "";

  // Setting up the cookie value
  cookieStr = c_name + "=" + escape(c_value) + "; ";

  // Determining the expiration date increase: days or hours
  if (c_exdays) { // Adds days to current date
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + (c_exdays));
  } 
  else if (c_exhours) { // Adds hours to current date
    exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + c_exhours);
  }

  // Setting up the cookie expiration date
  cookieStr += "expires=" + exdate.toUTCString() + "; ";
  
  // Setting up the cookie Path
  if (c_path) {
    cookieStr += "path=" + c_path + "; ";
  }

  // Setting up the cookie Domain
  if (c_domain) {
    cookieStr += "domain=" + c_domain + "; ";
  }
  
  console.log(cookieStr);

  // Creating the cookie 
  document.cookie = cookieStr;
}
```

**EDIT**: adding console log output.

The console output I am looking at seems erratic to me. That is because I am expecting the `SomeCookieName` value should be the same *every time*. Note there are two `console.log` look at the snippet above and try it to look at the console output yourself:

> SomeCookieName=0; expires=Fri, 29 Jan 2016 23:14:34 GMT; path=/; domain=*.somedomainname.com;
>
> SomeCookieName=0; _ga=GA1.2.988843064.1445444954; BCSI-CS-9cd60cd21b772d48=2
>
> SomeCookieName=1; expires=Fri, 29 Jan 2016 23:14:35 GMT; path=/; domain=*.somedomainname.com;
>
> SomeCookieName=0; _ga=GA1.2.988843064.1445444954; BCSI-CS-9cd60cd21b772d48=2
>
> SomeCookieName=1; expires=Fri, 29 Jan 2016 23:14:36 GMT; path=/; domain=*.somedomainname.com;
>
> SomeCookieName=0; _ga=GA1.2.988843064.1445444954; BCSI-CS-9cd60cd21b772d48=2
>
> SomeCookieName=1; expires=Fri, 29 Jan 2016 23:15:02 GMT; path=/; domain=*.somedomainname.com;
>
> SomeCookieName=0; _ga=GA1.2.988843064.1445444954; BCSI-CS-9cd60cd21b772d48=2
>
> SomeCookieName=1; expires=Fri, 29 Jan 2016 23:15:03 GMT; path=/; domain=*.somedomainname.com;
>
> SomeCookieName=0; _ga=GA1.2.988843064.1445444954; BCSI-CS-9cd60cd21b772d48=2

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2oh4665w/

Comment: @Fabricator can you elaborate? I am looking at the console output and I see that the values are different for `SomeCookieName`

Comment: it's setting it to 0 or 1 every time. are you expecting the cookie value to stick after it's set for the first time?

Comment: @Fabricator setting it to 0 or 1 is right. I expect this: creating the cookie with value of 0, console log the cookie should show me that the value is 0, same thing if the value is 1 when the cookie is being created, the console log should show the cookie value is 1. Does that make sense? I think I am not correctly updating the cookie value *because* it is not showing me the described behavior... otherwise I am misinterpreting something and I can't see what it is

Comment: @Fabricator Your fiddle does not work for me, because the domain is incorrect -- I don't see `SomeCookieName` being set at all. (Does it really work for you? Or am I completely misunderstanding what the objective here is?) I modified the domain so that does indeed work, as far as I can understand the objective: https://jsfiddle.net/2oh4665w/1/ (OP: is that the behavior your expect?)

Comment: @Fabricator the domain name being wrong seems to be the case, I didn't know that would happen... not even an error message thrown for incorrect parameter values, thanks JavaScript! Anyways make this an official answer, it demonstrates the point of this question: How to update a cookie **properly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a `domain` parameter when setting `document.cookie`, then in order to read that cookie, the `domain` must match the domain/subdomain of the page where the script is running.

In this case, you probably set a `SomeCookieName=0` with a domain, earlier, while testing. Then, you tried to change it, but you included an invalid `domain`, so the cookie was not set.

If you make `domain` match your actual domain, or omit it entirely, the cookie will be set and change as you reset it.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea this would happen, especially because errors where not thrown over invalid parameters i.e. invalid domain